# New to Rails 4 Testing - Need help getting started (rSpec and Devise)

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rspec2

I'm relatively new to testing and very new to Rails 4 and rSpec. I am trying to test a controller that uses Devise for authentication and I am stuck. All of the examples I can find are for Rails 3.

I'm using Rails 4.0.3, Devise 3.2.3, rSpec 2.14.1 and FactoryGirl 4.4.0.

```
class LessonPlansController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /lesson_plans
  def index
    @lesson_plans = current_user.lesson_plans.to_a
  end

  .
  .
  .

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_lesson_plan
    @lesson_plan = LessonPlan.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
  def lesson_plan_params
    params[:lesson_plan]
  end

  def lesson_plan_params
    params.require(:lesson_plan).permit(:title, :synopsis)
  end
end
```

Here are my factory definitions: (Maybe I don't need to define user_id in the lesson_plan factory?)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
    sequence( :username )  { |n| "user#{n}" }
    sequence( :email )     { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
    password               'foobarbaz'
    password_confirmation  'foobarbaz'
    created_at             Time.now
    updated_at             Time.now
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :lesson_plan do
    user_id 1
    title    "The French Revolution"
    synopsis "Background and events leading up to the French Revolution"
  end
end
```

And the test part is where I get stuck.

```
describe LessonPlansController do
  let(:valid_attributes) { {  } }
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  # describe "GET index" do
  it "assigns all lesson_plans as @lesson_plans" do
    user=FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in user
    lesson_plan = LessonPlan.create! valid_attributes
    get :index, {}, valid_session
    assigns(:lesson_plans).should eq([lesson_plan])
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what to put in valid_attributes and valid_session (or if I even need them). The test will get as far as signing in the user, but will fail on creation of the lesson_plan. Admittedly this is the default/generated test for rSpec, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Examples I have seen use a before block to set up the user. I haven't been able to find anything on the Devise wiki page covering how to write basic rSpec tests for a controller that requires the user to be logged in. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The spec is likely failing at that point because you're tying to create a lesson plan with no attributes.

Comment: That makes sense. I will look closer at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"I'm not sure what to put in valid_attributes and valid_session (or if I even need them)."`

Well that depends what you're testing for.. Say you're testing validations & want to ensure that a record not be created if x column is set to null... then you could try to specifically create a record with invalid attributes (e.g. `column: nil`) and expect the result to not return true; maybe you want to ensure that it IS created with valid attributes.

You can btw, use `attributes_for(:factory_name)`` since you're using FactoryGirl. And no you don't necessarily need to specify the user's id in your lesson plan factory; unless you always want it to reference user 1. You can simply reference user with no value. Check out http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/12/testing-series-intro.html and especially parts 3-5 for an introduction to testing with RSPec.. I found this a pretty easy to follow guide when I was getting started.

Comment: I have a tests (that pass) for the lesson_plan model. I will try using `attributes_for(:lesson_plan)` but I'm wondering how to pass in that the lesson plan should be created for the current user since that is how my controller creates a lesson plan: `@lesson_plan = current_user.lesson_plans.new(lesson_plan_params)`

Comment: I bought the book Everyday Testing with rSpec. I'm mostly hung up on the Devise part. The Everyday series is very helpful.

Comment: Also.. I recommend adding `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` to your spec helper.. this allows you to call `create()`, `build()`, etc.. without the `FactoryGirl` prefix

Comment: You can just override the user's id (or user..depending on how you have your factory defined and the way in which you're creating new records) to associate it with a user... for instance `create(:lesson_plan, user_id: user.id). Don't worry about testing Devise functionality too deeply.. that's why they provide helper methods like `sign_in`.. Use these helpers to get to a specific state in your app and test what your own code should do from then on. For helpers.. your best reference will be Devise's own documentation, in the testing portion of the guide.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved it by changing the build line to: `lesson_plan = LessonPlan.create! attributes_for(:lesson_plan, :user => user)` as you suggested, adding the user parameter.